# Admin Page error "The page isn't redirecting properly" after changing base url in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1.1

I have changed my base url in magento 2.1. After that frontend is working fine but admin page giving me "The page isn't redirecting properly. website redirected you too many times" error. Please help me on this.

Comment: how you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set http for admin section. Please check your settings in admin base url settings.

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me too, I could not access the admin back-end to change admin base URL setting. I did the following and it worked.
I ran this query 
`UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '1' WHERE path='web/secure/use_in_adminhtml'`
directly in the database and then ran
 `php bin/magento cache:clean`